# How to do json to .net

Tags: .net, json

How to get product id of category data into `json` to `.net` and if their sub category present also get that.

http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)/Category
           from `json` to `.net` like Id, Name,Description etc

```
{ 
  "d" : {

results:{ 

    "__metadata": {

      "uri": "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories(0)",
      "type": "DataServiceProviderDemo.Category" }, 
      "ID": 0,
      "Name": "Food", 
      "Products": [ {

        "__metadata": {

          "uri": "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)",
          "etag": "W/"0"", 
          "type": "DataServiceProviderDemo.Product" 
        }, 
        "ID": 0, 
        "Name": "Bread", 
        "Description": "Whole grain bread", 
        "ReleaseDate": "/Date(694224000000)/",
        "DiscontinuedDate": null, 
        "Rating": 4, 
        "Price": "2.5", 
        "Concurrency": 0, 
        "Category": { 

          "__deferred": { 
            "uri": 

"http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)/Category"

          } 

        }, 

        "Supplier": {

          "__deferred": { 
            "uri": "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)/Supplier"

          } 
        } 
      } 
    ] 
  }

} 

}
```

Comment: google "parse json in .net" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)